# Questions about four-momemtum

Tags: general-relativity

I am reading a note about Kerr metric, following is some screen shot where I have problems.

---

[image]

[image]

---

First of all, I think the author made a mistake. It should be
$$
E=-u_\mu k^\mu=u^t\;\;\;L=u_\mu m^\mu=u_\phi
$$
My questions are:

1) we have $E=u_t$, not $u^t$, why the author says

> they are the energy at infinity per mass unit...

2) For massless particle, why can we choose properly the affine parameter so that the four-momentum coincide with the four velocity?

I have done some google search about the four-momentum, such as [this post](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=447718). Are there two kinds of definitions?

$$
P^\mu=mU^\mu=(-E,p_1,p_2,p_3)
$$

and
$$
P_\mu=mU_\mu=(E,p_1,p_2,p_3)
$$

? If so, how can these two be consistent? I don't think we have
$$
-E=P^0=P_ag^{a0}=Eg^{00}+p_ag^{a0}
$$

Comment: Not sure how you could be this far into a GR course and not have seen [covariant and contravariant vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_and_contravariance_of_vectors), but $p^\mu$ and $p_\mu$ are both correct.

Comment: @KyleKanos, I know covariant and contravarient vectors. My question is, are these two definition consistence? You see, the first components of both vectors are $\pm E$, but I can't see that they satisfy the transformation law as listed in my post.

Comment: Have you tried converting from covariant to contravariant by applying the metric? That should answer your question immediately.

Comment: @KyleKanos, is the metric necessarily Minkowski?

Comment: Isn't the role of the metric to convert between contravariant and covariant vectors, regardless of its name? The Kerr metric follows the $(-,+,+,+)$ signature, so it should give you the $\pm E$ difference you see.